# Rename row.name in data frame using matches or partial matches from a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame in R with 341 rows. I want to rename the row names using a list with 349 names. All 341 names will be in this list for sure. But not all of them will be perfect hits.
The data looks like this

```
rownames(df_RPM1)
[1] "LQNS02059392.1_11686_5p"
[2] "LQNS02277998.1_30984_3p"
[3] "LQNS02277998.1_30984_5p"
[4] "LQNS02277998.1_30988_3p"
[5] "LQNS02277998.1_30988_5p"
[6] "LQNS02277997.1_30943_3p"
[7] "miR-9|LQNS02278070.1_31740_3p"
[8] "miR-9|LQNS02278094.1_36129_3p" 

head(inlist)
[1] "dpu-miR-2-03_LQNS02059392.1_11686_5p"  "dpu-miR-10-P2_LQNS02277998.1_30984_3p"
[3] "dpu-miR-10-P2_LQNS02277998.1_30984_5p" "dpu-miR-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988_3p"
[5] "dpu-miR-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988_5p" "miR-9|LQNS02278070.1_31740_3p" 
[6] "miR-9|LQNS02278094.1_36129_3p"
```

The order won't necessarily be the same in the two.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this in R?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I replace the question with the real data, the only pattern is that the different ones will start with ```dpu-miR-*_LQ*```

Comment: So you want to change the rownames of `df_RPM1` with the matching values in `inlist` ? Some of the rownames match exactly to `inlist` like `miR-9|LQNS02278094.1_36129_3p`) and for the ones which do not match you want to extract the relevant data and then match (like `LQNS02059392.1_11686_5p` ) ?

Comment: So for the ones that don't match i want to find the matching part and then rewrite as dpu-matching_part

Comment: How do you define the matching part? For example one can say "LQN" is matching in all of them, so how do you decide which one to select ?

Comment: A partial match looks like this: LQNS02277998.1_30984_3p =  dpu-miR-10-P2_***LQNS02277998.1_30984_3p***
A complete match will look like this miR-993|LQNS02276924.1_23274_3p = ***miR-993|LQNS02276924.1_23274_3p***

Comment: For instance this would work: ```df_RPM1 %>% replace(., sapply(rownames(df_RPM1), function(.) grepl('LQNS02277998.1_30984_3p',.)), "dpu-miR-10-P2_LQNS02277998.1_30984_3p")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a lot what a "non-perfect hit" looks like. Assuming the row name is a substring of the real name, `str_detect()` does the job quite well:

```
library(tidyverse)
real_names <- c("dpu-miR-2-03_LQNS02059392.1_11686_5p",
                  "dpu-miR-10-P2_LQNS02277998.1_30984_3p",
                  "dpu-miR-10-P2_LQNS02277998.1_30984_5p",
                  "dpu-miR-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988_3p",
                  "dpu-miR-10-P3_LQNS02277998.1_30988_5p",
                  "miR-9|LQNS02278070.1_31740_3p",
                  "miR-9|LQNS02278094.1_36129_3p")

str_which(real_names, "LQNS02059392.1_11686_5p")
#> [1]  1
```

So we can vectorize (I removed the element 6 which is not found in the example list):

```
pos <- map_int(rownames(df_RPM1), ~ str_which(real_names, fixed(.)))
pos
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

And all that's left is to change the row names:

```
rownames(df_RPM1) <- real_names[pos]
```

Of course, if a non-perfect hit means something more complicated, you may need to create a regex from the row names or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, trying it but I got stuck at ```Error: Result 42 must be a single integer, not an integer vector of length 2
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.```

Comment: That means one of the row names (the nb 42) matched with 2 of the "real names". You should look at it and understand why and how to choose the correct match. You could just take the first result with `pos <- map_int(rownames(df_RPM1), ~ str_which(real_names, fixed(.))[[1]])` but it may be totally wrong depending on the context.

Comment: Okay, that was very useful, i found all the instances where i needed to solve that problem, or strings not being exact matches. THANKS!